# Runtime Width of a layout element inside an Auto Layout Group in Unity 4.6

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I try to get the width of an element inside a `VerticalLayoutGroup`

```
var width = (element.transform as RectTransform).rect.width;
```

but I get back `0` since the `RectTransform` is being driven by the Auto Layout. How can I measure the runtime width?

**Edit**

I am trying to scale a `RawImage`